# How can I change the start and end times of a day?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a website on WordPress (currently editing a child theme) where we list showtimes for concerts. As of now, shows past midnight are showing up under the next date. I'd like late-night shows to be included with other shows from the same night, so ideally, my code would consider the 'day' to end at 4 am rather than 11:59 pm.

I didn't write the code originally and I don't know much about coding but I have a basic understanding. I would appreciate any help.

```
get_header();

$filter_by_time = current_time('Y-m-d') . ' 05:01:00';
$actual_time = intval(current_time('G'));
if ($actual_time < 5) {
    $filter_by_time = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-1 days")) . ' 05:01:00';
}
//$last_date_of_month = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(current_time('Y-m-t') . ' +1 day')) . ' 05:00:59';
$first_date_of_next_month = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(current_time('Y-m-t') . ' +1 day'));
$last_date_of_month = $first_date_of_next_month . ' 05:00:59';

$query_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'event',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_key' => 'date',
    'meta_type' => 'DATETIME',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'date',
            'value' => array($filter_by_time, $last_date_of_month),
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
            'type' => 'DATETIME'
        )
    )
);
$events_query = new WP_Query($query_args);

if ($events_query->have_posts()) {
    $present_date = false;
    $black = false;
    $output = '';
    $ajax_url = admin_url('admin-ajax.php') . '?action=get_popup_content&eventId=';

    while ($events_query->have_posts()) {
        $events_query->the_post();
        $from_date = get_field('date', get_the_ID());
        $ymd_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($from_date));

        if ($present_date === false || $present_date !== $ymd_date) {
            if ($present_date !== false) {
                $stage_one_output .= '</ul></div>';
                $stage_two_output .= '</ul></div>';
                $stage_three_output .= '</ul></div>';

                $output .= $stage_one_output . $stage_two_output . $stage_three_output;

                $output .= '</div>';
                $output .= '</div>';
                $output .= '</div>';
                $output .= '<hr class="wp-block-separator aligncenter is-style-wide">';
                $output .= '</div>';
//                $color = $black ? '#fafcfc' : '#171717';
//                $output .= '<div class="nectar-shape-divider-wrap" style="height:50px;" data-front="true" data-style="curve" data-position="bottom"><svg class="nectar-shape-divider" fill="' . $color . '" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1000 100" preserveAspectRatio="none"><path d="M 0 0 c 0 0 200 50 500 50 s 500 -50 500 -50 v 101 h -1000 v -100 z"></path></svg></div>';
                $output .= '</div>';
//                $black = !$black;
            }
            $present_date = $ymd_date;
            $stage_one_output = '';
            $stage_two_output = '';
            $stage_three_output = '';
            $container_class = $black ? ' main-content-bl' : '';
            $output .= '<div class="container-fluid main-content-top' . $container_class . '" data-date="' . $ymd_date . '">';
            $output .= '<div class="container">';
            $output .= '<div class="row">';
            $output .= '<div class="home-container-wh">';
            $output .= '<h2 class="title">' . date('l, M j', strtotime($ymd_date)) . '</h2>';
            $output .= '<div class="row">';
            $image_color = $black ? 'bl' : 'wh';
            $stage_one_output .= '<div class="span_4">'
                    . '<div class="stage-number text-center">'
                    . '<div class="stage-title has-additional-height">
                                <img class="additional-height" src="' . get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/' . $image_color . '-stage01.png" width="" height="" alt="" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <ul>';
            $stage_two_output .= '<div class="span_4">'
                    . '<div class="stage-number text-center">'
                    . '<div class="stage-title">
                                <img src="' . get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/' . $image_color . '-stage02.png" width="" height="" alt="" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <ul>';
            $stage_three_output .= '<div class="span_4">'
                    . '<div class="stage-number text-center">'
                    . '<div class="stage-title">
                                <img src="' . get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/' . $image_color . '-stage03.png" width="" height="" alt="" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <ul>';
        }

        $stages = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'stage');
        $last_stage = '';
        if ($stages && !is_wp_error($stages)) {
            foreach ($stages as $stage) {
                $last_stage = $stage->name;
            }
        }
        $date = get_field('date', get_the_ID());
        $mins = date('i', strtotime($date));
        if (intval($mins) > 0) {
            $times = date('g:ia', strtotime($date));
        } else {
            $times = date('ga', strtotime($date));
        }
        $title = get_the_title();
        $title_to_show = $title;
        if (strlen($title) > 75) {
            $pos = strpos($title, ' ', 65);
            $title_to_show = substr($title, 0, $pos) . '...';
        }
        $event_output = '<li><span>' . $times . '</span><div class="event-list-title">'
                . '<a data-fancybox data-type="ajax" data-src="' . $ajax_url . get_the_ID() . '" class="" href="javascript:;">' . $title_to_show . '</a>'
                . '</div>'
                . '</li>';
        if ($last_stage != '') {
            switch ($last_stage) {
                case '1':
                    $stage_one_output .= $event_output;
                    break;
                case '2':
                    $stage_two_output .= $event_output;
                    break;
                case '3':
                    $stage_three_output .= $event_output;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    $stage_one_output .= '</ul></div>';
    $stage_two_output .= '</ul></div>';
    $stage_three_output .= '</ul></div>';

    $output .= $stage_one_output . $stage_two_output . $stage_three_output;

    $output .= '</div>';
    $output .= '</div>';
    $output .= '</div>';
    $output .= '<hr class="wp-block-separator aligncenter is-style-wide">';
    $output .= '</div>';
//    $color = $black ? '#fafcfc' : '#171717';
//    $output .= '<div class="nectar-shape-divider-wrap" style="height:50px;" data-front="true" data-style="curve" data-position="bottom"><svg class="nectar-shape-divider" fill="' . $color . '" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1000 100" preserveAspectRatio="none"><path d="M 0 0 c 0 0 200 50 500 50 s 500 -50 500 -50 v 101 h -1000 v -100 z"></path></svg></div>';
    $output .= '</div>';
    echo '<div class="events-container">';
    echo $output;
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div class="next-month-link-container">';
    echo '<a href="/events/?bydate=' . $first_date_of_next_month . '">NEXT MONTH &gt;&gt;</a>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo rw_generate_skip_to_html();
    echo '<div class="loading-indicator-container">
        <img class="loading-indicator" src="' . get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/roll.gif" width="55" height="55" alt="" />
    </div>';
} else {
    $filter_by_time = $first_date_of_next_month . ' 05:01:00';
    $first_date_of_next_month = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(date('Y-m-t', strtotime($first_date_of_next_month)) . ' +1 day'));
    $last_date_of_month = $first_date_of_next_month . ' 05:00:59';
    
    $query_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'event',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_key' => 'date',
        'meta_type' => 'DATETIME',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'date',
                'value' => array($filter_by_time, $last_date_of_month),
                'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                'type' => 'DATETIME'
            )
        )
    );
    $events_query = new WP_Query($query_args);

    if ($events_query->have_posts()) {
        $present_date = false;
        $black = false;
        $output = '';
        $ajax_url = admin_url('admin-ajax.php') . '?action=get_popup_content&eventId=';

        while ($events_query->have_posts()) {
            $events_query->the_post();
            $from_date = get_field('date', get_the_ID());
            $ymd_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($from_date));

            if ($present_date === false || $present_date !== $ymd_date) {
                if ($present_date !== false) {
                    $stage_one_output .= '</ul></div>';
                    $stage_two_output .= '</ul></div>';
                    $stage_three_output .= '</ul></div>';

                    $output .= $stage_one_output . $stage_two_output . $stage_three_output;

                    $output .= '</div>';
                    $output .= '</div>';
                    $output .= '</div>';
                    $output .= '<hr class="wp-block-separator aligncenter is-style-wide">';
                    $output .= '</div>';
//                $color = $black ? '#fafcfc' : '#171717';
//                $output .= '<div class="nectar-shape-divider-wrap" style="height:50px;" data-front="true" data-style="curve" data-position="bottom"><svg class="nectar-shape-divider" fill="' . $color . '" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1000 100" preserveAspectRatio="none"><path d="M 0 0 c 0 0 200 50 500 50 s 500 -50 500 -50 v 101 h -1000 v -100 z"></path></svg></div>';
                    $output .= '</div>';
//                $black = !$black;
                }
                $present_date = $ymd_date;
                $stage_one_output = '';
                $stage_two_output = '';
                $stage_three_output = '';
                $container_class = $black ? ' main-content-bl' : '';
                $output .= '<div class="container-fluid main-content-top' . $container_class . '" data-date="' . $ymd_date . '">';
                $output .= '<div class="container">';
                $output .= '<div class="row">';
                $output .= '<div class="home-container-wh">';
                $output .= '<h2 class="title">' . date('l, M j', strtotime($ymd_date)) . '</h2>';
                $output .= '<div class="row">';
                $image_color = $black ? 'bl' : 'wh';
                $stage_one_output .= '<div class="span_4">'
                        . '<div class="stage-number text-center">'
                        . '<div class="stage-title has-additional-height">
                                <img class="additional-height" src="' . get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/' . $image_color . '-stage01.png" width="" height="" alt="" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <ul><li style="justify-content: center;"><div style="color: #770016;" class="event-list-title">Reopening early 2022 - Stay Tuned!</div></li>';
                $stage_two_output .= '<div class="span_4">'
                        . '<div class="stage-number text-center">'
                        . '<div class="stage-title">
                                <img src="' . get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/' . $image_color . '-stage02.png" width="" height="" alt="" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <ul>';
                $stage_three_output .= '<div class="span_4">'
                        . '<div class="stage-number text-center">'
                        . '<div class="stage-title">
                                <img src="' . get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/' . $image_color . '-stage03.png" width="" height="" alt="" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <ul>';
            }

            $stages = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'stage');
            $last_stage = '';
            if ($stages && !is_wp_error($stages)) {
                foreach ($stages as $stage) {
                    $last_stage = $stage->name;
                }
            }
            $date = get_field('date', get_the_ID());
            $mins = date('i', strtotime($date));
            if (intval($mins) > 0) {
                $times = date('g:ia', strtotime($date));
            } else {
                $times = date('ga', strtotime($date));
            }
            $title = get_the_title();
            $title_to_show = $title;
            if (strlen($title) > 75) {
                $pos = strpos($title, ' ', 65);
                $title_to_show = substr($title, 0, $pos) . '...';
            }
            $event_output = '<li><span>' . $times . '</span><div class="event-list-title">'
                    . '<a data-fancybox data-type="ajax" data-src="' . $ajax_url . get_the_ID() . '" class="" href="javascript:;">' . $title_to_show . '</a>'
                    . '</div>'
                    . '</li>';
            if ($last_stage != '') {
                switch ($last_stage) {
                    case '1':
                        $stage_one_output .= $event_output;
                        break;
                    case '2':
                        $stage_two_output .= $event_output;
                        break;
                    case '3':
                        $stage_three_output .= $event_output;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        $stage_one_output .= '</ul></div>';
        $stage_two_output .= '</ul></div>';
        $stage_three_output .= '</ul></div>';

        $output .= $stage_one_output . $stage_two_output . $stage_three_output;

        $output .= '</div>';
        $output .= '</div>';
        $output .= '</div>';
        $output .= '<hr class="wp-block-separator aligncenter is-style-wide">';
        $output .= '</div>';
//    $color = $black ? '#fafcfc' : '#171717';
//    $output .= '<div class="nectar-shape-divider-wrap" style="height:50px;" data-front="true" data-style="curve" data-position="bottom"><svg class="nectar-shape-divider" fill="' . $color . '" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1000 100" preserveAspectRatio="none"><path d="M 0 0 c 0 0 200 50 500 50 s 500 -50 500 -50 v 101 h -1000 v -100 z"></path></svg></div>';
        $output .= '</div>';
        echo '<div class="events-container">';
        echo $output;
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="next-month-link-container">';
        echo '<a href="/events/?bydate=' . $first_date_of_next_month . '">NEXT MONTH &gt;&gt;</a>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo rw_generate_skip_to_html();
        echo '<div class="loading-indicator-container">
        <img class="loading-indicator" src="' . get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/roll.gif" width="55" height="55" alt="" />
    </div>';
    } else {
        echo '<h3 style="text-align: center;">No events found!</h3>';
    }
}

get_footer();
```

Comment: Why is this tagged Python?  That's not Python.

Comment: The main problem here is when you're checking `$present_date !== $ymd_date` - you're not taking into account times here, only the date part `"Y-m-d"`. There's a few different ways to approach this but all of them will have to compare the time part as well.